# Probability Distributions - Probability of x2 being larger than x1

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm working with some probability distributions, working towards figuring the outcome of a statistical process.

I have worked out my survey results, and I have a confidence interval (Confidence Level 0.95) established, along with a standard deviation.

Now, I'm trying to work out the following.  I've phrased it as clearly as I can, so it probably reads like a university exam question.

Let A(x) and B(x) be normal distributions with the same standard deviation, but different mean values.

Let $m$ represent the lower limit of $A$, and $n$ represent the upper limit of $A$, which represent the confidence interval (ie the actual result will be between them 95% of the time).  The events are independent of each other.

In the same way, let $j$ and $k$ represent the lower and upper limits of $B$ respectively, where $j < m < k < n$, meaning the two distributions overlap.

ie:

### $A=N(\sigma,\mu_{1})$,

### $B=N(\sigma,\mu_{2})$

where $\mu_{2} < \mu_{1}$

What is the probability that the eventual result of the process where B prevails over A?

ie: We end up with two points, $x_{1}\epsilon A$ and $x_{2}\epsilon B$,  is such that $x_{1} \leq x_{2}$ ?

My gut feeling is it is this:

### $\Large P \normalsize _{(x_{1} \leq x_{2})} = \Large \int_j^m[\normalsize B(x_{2}) * \int_m^k \! A(x_{1}) \mathrm dx \Large] \mathrm dx$

Am I on the right track here?  What's the correct formula?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are A and B independently distributed?

Comment: Yes - I think.  A will end up between m and n 95% of the time, and B will end up between j and k 95% of the time.  The only hiccup I can add is this - in the "real world" situation, there are sometimes more than two distributions, and as these are opinion poll results, the eventual outcomes will all add up to 100%. (If that makes them dependent, then so be it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since: $\mathsf P(B\leq A) = \mathsf P(A-B \geq 0)$

Then you wish to find the distribution of $(A-B)$ which is the [sum of two Normally distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

If $A\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{A}, \sigma_{A}^2)$ and $B\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{B}, \sigma_{B}^2)$ are independent, then: $$(A-B)\sim\mathcal N(\mu_{A}-\mu_{B}, \sigma_{A}^2+\sigma_{B}^2)$$

If the random variables are correlated, then we need to know the correlation coefficient $\rho$, and then you will have: $$(A-B)\sim\mathcal N(\mu_{A}-\mu_{B}, \sigma_{A}^2+\sigma_{B}^2-\rho_{{A},{B}}\;\sigma_{A}\;\sigma_{B})$$

Once you know the mean and variance of the difference, you can find: $\mathsf P(\frac{(A-B)-(\mu_{A-B})}{\sigma_{A-B}}>0)$

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around a lot of this stats stuff, which can be quite tricky.  I'm an engineering technologist rather than a statistician.  If the standard deviations are the same, does that simplify things?  And also, please help me out by explaining what "X1 ~" means in this context.  Is it to suggest that X1 is somewhere on N?

Comment: Sorry, $X_1$ would be $A$, and $X_2$ would be $B$, your use of $x_1\in A, x_2\in B$ muddled me.  Correctulated now.

Comment: With that solution for the independent variables, if we let Z ~ N( ...the sum of the normal distributions ...) then am I correct in understanding that P(Z <= w) is the probability of B being greater than A at point w on the axis, and, at which point, the integral of that would be the probability of B being greater than A for all A values up to that point?

Comment: Thank you.  I think this got me back on track.  Took me a while, but I have been able to finally get a lower and upper limit for the integration of the summed distribution, which will give me the probability that A >=B for the entire overlapping range.  From there, I can work out the probability that A will "win" and the probability that B will "win".